# Python: How to get hung process to release control back in concurrent.futures pool?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a parallelized a large CPU-intensive data processing task using the 
`concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor` method like shown below.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        futures_ocr = ([
            executor.submit(
                MyProcessor,
                folder
            ) for folder in sub_folders
        ])

        is_cancel = wait_for(futures_ocr)
        if is_cancel:
            print 'shutting down executor'
            executor.shutdown()

def wait_for(futures):
    """Handes the future tasks after completion"""

    cancelled = False

    try:
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures, timeout=200):
            try:
                result = future.result()
                print 'successfully finished processing folder: ', result.source_folder_path

            except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
                print 'TimeoutError occured'


            except TypeError:
                print 'TypeError occured'



    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '****** cancelling... *******'
        cancelled = True
        for future in futures:
            future.cancel()

    return cancelled
```

There are certain folders where the process seems to be stuck for a long time, not because of some error in the code but due to the nature of the files being processed. So, I wanted to timeout those types of processes, so that they return if a certain time limit is exceeded. The Pool can then use the process for the next available task.

Adding the timeout in the `as_completed()` function gives an error while completing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call_ocr.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "call_ocr.py", line 42, in main
    is_cancel = wait_for(futures_ocr)
  File "call_ocr.py", line 59, in wait_for
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures, timeout=200):
  File "/Users/saurav/.pyenv/versions/ocr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 216, in as_completed
    len(pending), len(fs)))
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: 3 (of 3) futures unfinished
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what is the best way to cause timedout processes to stop and relinquish the process back to the Process pool?

Answer (score 0):

The `concurrent.futures` implementation does not support such use case.

The `timeout` which can be passed to its functions and methods allows to set for how long to wait for results but has no effect on the actual computation itself.

The [pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library supports such use case.

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from pebble import ProcessPool

def function(n):
    return n

with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.schedule(function, args=[1], timeout=10)

    try:
        results = future.result()
    except TimeoutError as error:
        print("function took longer than %d seconds" % error.args[1])
```